# STL reading from file

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector, declared this way:

```
vector<const char*>Words;
```

How can I read the data from a file into this vector, using fopen, fgets and fclose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to take in a buffer of characters.
So Words should be `vector<char>` In case your requirement is getting a container of `const char*` (that would be list of strings) you can build a solution of top of the vector of characters by splitting on your desired set of deliminator.

```
Words.resize(maxBufferSize);
fgets(Words.data(), maxBufferSize, fp);
```

See [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) for reference

I would have personally preferred using [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream).

```
std::ifstream fin(filename);
std::vector<char> Words{ std::istream_iterator<char>{fin},
                               std::istream_iterator<char>{}};
```

In case your input file is already deliminated by whitespaces, then you can do

```
 std::vector<string> Words{ std::istream_iterator<string>{fin},
                               std::istream_iterator<string>{}};
```

As mentioned in the comments by using `std::string` you save yourself a lot of trouble around memory management etc.

Comment: Is the memory pointed by all those const char* allocated by the constructor of the vector?

Comment: As previous commenter indicated, you need to be careful about memory mgmt. Putting stuff in a string or a shared ptr and pushing that to a vector is usually much safer. Use RAII, it is one of the great idioms of C++!

Comment: I would definitely use `std::string` instead of `const char*`

Comment: Updated based on comments.